# Writing an equation based on two machines speeds

Tags: algorithm, math, analysis, equation

How do you write an equation describing the times between two algorithms? Example: Algorithm x has an average run time of T(n)=8n^3.

Machine A performs 10 arithmetic operations per second, while machine B performs 20 arithmetic operations per second.

Machine A can (conceptually) run 4.217 inputs per minute where as
Machine B can (conceptually) run 5.313 inputs per minute

How would I write an equation describing the relationship between the two inputs?

Comment: Which kind of “relationship” do you mean? Difference of the sizes of maximal inputs that are processed in under a minute on average?

Comment: You wrote about “4.217 inputs” but you seem to be referring to “an input of size 4.217”. Is the latter correct?

Answer (score 0):

Consider analogy with Velocity/Time/Distance:

```
Distance = Velocity * Time
```

For your case

```
Performance(op/sec) * time(sec) = number of operations

10(op/s) * 60(s) = 8*(4.217)^3 = 600
20(op/s) * 60(s) = 8*(5.313)^3 = 1200
```